# limit media upload to once a day

Tags: uploads, media

Is there a way (with hook or plugin) to limit media upload to once a day per user? I can only find related articles about limit file size.

Edit: The reason I want to use this is I'm setting up a social site where people share images. I'm seeing an increase in data usage and would like to have a bit control in the setup fase.

I'm now controlling image file size (set to max 1MB per file) and a quota per user profile for 50MB. But it would be perfect to set max upload on 1 per day.

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: Please not that plugin recommendations are off topic.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a meta field for users identifying that user when he already uploaded something in that day (or in the last 24 hours).

After you do that, you will need to create a function to trigger in some upload action, like `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` or `wp_handle_upload` to check if user can upload something today, returning a error if not.

It can be done, but it will not be simple as putting a single function on your theme.

Comment: You mean something like after upload add a meta field value like uploadedFriday and check with new upload if uploadedFriday = uploadedFriday, sorry you can't upload more media today. In that direction? And a function to update the meta field value and a function which catches the upload handle to check if uploading is approved?

Comment: I have found a plugin which matches my wishes and is much faster than developing this for my own. Thanks Bruno for your thoughts!